# Declaring a dll name at run time

Tags: c#

Is there a way to insert a library name into a DLLImport statement at run time based on program parameters.

Answer (score 4):

No, but it sounds like you want to do a dynamic PInvoke, which is possible.

See the technique using Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer described here: [Dynamic PInvoke](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/07/14/181932.aspx) in Junfeng Zhang's Windows Programming Notes.